# Resolving explicitly the scope of a class member

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, c++14

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    void fun() const { std::cout << "foo::fun()" << std::endl; }
};

auto main() -> int {
  foo f;
  f.fun();
  f.foo::fun();

  return 0;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1f6b32d7f1ee921)

- As shown in the above example, member function `foo::fun()` is evoked with two different ways.
- In the second call (i.e., `f.foo::fun()`), the scope of member class `foo::fun()` is explicitly disambiguated/Resolved.

**Questions:**

1. What's the difference between the two calls (i.e., `f.fun()` and `f.foo::fun()`)?
2. Are there any advantages in calling a member function or a publicly accessible member variable by explicitly disambiguating its scope against calling it in the classical way?
3. Are there any pitfalls in calling a member function or a publicly accessible member variable by explicitly disambiguating its scope?

Comment: Note that explicit scope would enable you to access the parent's version of `fun()`. [__Demo__](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/597be4cd06d26f76).

Comment: Ugh `auto main() -> int` just stop it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One difference is that if `fun()` were a `virtual` function, calling it the second way would inhibit virtual dispatch.

```
struct foo {
    void virtual fun() const { std::cout << "foo::fun()" << std::endl; }
};
struct bar : foo {
    void fun() const override { std::cout << "bar::fun()" << std::endl; }
};

auto main() -> int {
  bar b;
  foo *f = &b;
  f->fun();
  f->foo::fun();
}
```

Outputs:

```
bar::fun()
foo::fun()
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/743056f1df0d8a91)

---

Similarly if you were instead hiding a function from the base class, it allows you to access the base class version.

```
struct foo {
    void fun() const { std::cout << "foo::fun()" << std::endl; }
};
struct bar : foo {
    void fun(int) const { std::cout << "bar::fun()" << std::endl; }
};

auto main() -> int {
  bar b;
  b.fun(10);
  b.foo::fun();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example there is no any semantic difference of the calling syntax.

However consider the following example

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
   void f() { std::cout << "A::f()" << std::endl; }
};

struct B : A
{
   void f() { std::cout << "B::f()" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
   B b;

   b.f();
   b.A::f();
}
```

Or consider a more interesting example though it has no any greate sense but it is interesting from the point of view of the scope resolution.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    virtual ~A() { std::cout << "A::~A()" << std::endl; };
};

struct B : A
{
     ~B() { std::cout << "B::~B()" << std::endl; };
};


int main() 
{
    B b1;

    b1.~A();

    std::cout << "End of the first part\n\n";

    B b2;

    b2.A::~A();

    std::cout << "End of the second part\n\n" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output will be

```
B::~B()
A::~A()
End of the first part

A::~A()
End of the second part


B::~B()
A::~A()
B::~B()
A::~A()
```

Take into account that I called purposely destructor with name `~A`

Comment: Note: calling the destructor twice, or using the object after the first destructor call, causes undefined behaviour. The output after "End of the second part" is not defined.

Comment: @Matt McNabb It is only that to demonstrate the scope resolution.:)